# Saving spot color channel file as a TIFF in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, spot-color, channel

Is there a way to save a photoshop file as a TIFF with multiple spot channels in CMYK mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. merely tick the `Spot Colors` option when saving the Tif with Photoshop...

[image]

Whether or not those channels are visible, accessible, and separate properly in anything *other* than Photoshop may be another matter.

In most instances, saving as a .PSD, .PDF, or .DCS2 is best if you have spot channels.

Answer (score 0):

yes - save the spot colours as new channels - you can then bring them into illustrator and they'll be there as spot layers.

Comment: Just note that if the plan is then place that Illustrator file into a layout application, such as InDesign or XPress... a Tiff will not "round trip" any spot colors from Illustrator. You need psd, dcs, or pdf for round trip spot colors.